# Woocommerce linking attributes and terms

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

I am creating a search form for woocommerce, such that I can choose some of the options pulled from attributes, and then when I submit that I'll get a refined selection of products. I have created a selection for attributes, but I cannot get the terms from the specific attributes. How can I link those two?

```
global $woocommerce, $post, $product;

    $class = ' dnd_service_box_' . $class;

    $attribute_array = array();
    $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

    if ( $attribute_taxonomies ){
        foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $tax ){
            if ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name ) ) ){
                $attribute_array[ $tax->attribute_name ] = $tax->attribute_name;                                    
            }
        }
    }


    $options = array();
    $options[] = "<option value=''>--?--</option>";
    foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $tax ) {
        $options[] = "<option value='{$tax->attribute_name}'>{$tax->attribute_label}</option>";
    }   

    $return = '<div class="dnd_sentence_search'.$class.'">
                    <h3>'._e('Attributes','theme').'</h3>
                    <select class="" id="attributes" size="1" name="attributes">
                        '.implode("\n", $options).'
                    </select>

                </div>';

    return $return;
```

This will return the attributes. And when I do `print_r($attribute_taxonomies);` I get out this

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attribute_id] => 2
        [attribute_name] => product-year
        [attribute_label] => Year
        [attribute_type] => select
        [attribute_orderby] => menu_order
    ) ...
```

How can I access all the terms from these taxonomies and how to make it so that when I choose one (like Year), in the other selection I'll only see the terms from the Year attribute?

EDIT:

I added another code that will give me terms

```
foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $tax) {
    if (taxonomy_exists(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name))){
        $taxonomy_terms[$tax->attribute_name] = get_terms( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name));
    }
}
```

Now my `$attribute_taxonomies` produces this kind of array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [attribute_id] => 2
            [attribute_name] => product-year
            [attribute_label] => Year
            [attribute_type] => select
            [attribute_orderby] => menu_order
        ) ...
```

From with I can get all the names and labels. The $taxonomy_terms will give mi this kind of array:

```
Array
(
    [product-year] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [term_id] => 77
                    [name] => 1989
                    [slug] => 1989
                    [term_group] => 0
                    [term_taxonomy_id] => 82
                    [taxonomy] => pa_product-year
                    [description] => 
                    [parent] => 0
                    [count] => 6
                    [meta_id] => 22
                    [woocommerce_term_id] => 77
                    [meta_key] => order_pa_product-year
                    [meta_value] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
```

So for each `attribute-name` I'm getting corresponding terms. But these are different arrays. First one is a simple array, and I thing that the second is multidimensional array.

Is there a way of checking if the attribute_name from the first one matches the key from the second one, and then I just need to get the values from the second array. This sounds very complicated...

EDIT2: Ok I figured out how to display the terms, but I still would like to link it:

```
$attribute_array = array();
$taxonomy_terms = array();
$attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

if ( $attribute_taxonomies ){
    foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $tax ){
        if ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name ) ) ){
            $attribute_array[ $tax->attribute_name ] = $tax->attribute_name;                                    
        }
    }
}

foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $tax) {
    if (taxonomy_exists(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name))){
        $taxonomy_terms[$tax->attribute_name] = get_terms( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name));
    }
}


$options = array();
$options_terms = array();
$options[] = "<option value=''>--?--</option>";
$options_terms[] = "<option value=''>--?--</option>";
foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $tax ) {
    $options[] = "<option value='{$tax->attribute_name}'>{$tax->attribute_label}</option>";
    foreach ($attribute_array as $key ) {
        if ($key == $tax->attribute_name) {
            foreach ($taxonomy_terms[$key] as $term) {
                $options_terms[] = "<option value='{$term->name}'>{$term->name}</option>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I do this part with jquery? Or can I link them with php?

EDIT3:

I edited the option value for the terms options so that the value corresponds the attribute name

```
$options_terms[] = "<option value='{$tax->attribute_name}'>{$term->name}</option>";
```

Now I could link them somehow if the values are the same, no?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I created a shortcode that did what I needed, easier and without this hassle :D